# Im trying to create a webpage which contains three Javascript objects

Tags: javascript

```js
// Create an object:
var person1 = {Title: "Title: A Song of Ice and Fire", Author: "Author: George RR Martin", Type:"Type: Paperback", Price:19.99};
var person2 = {Title:"Title: The Woman in the Window", Author:"Author: A.J. Finn", Type:"Type: Paperback", Price:6.29};
var person3 = {Title:"Title: The Silkworm", Author:"Author: Robert Galbraith", Type:"Type: Hardback", Price:14.99};

// Display some data from the object:
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = person1.Title;
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = person1.Author;
document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = person1.Type;
document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML = person1.Price;

document.getElementById("code1").innerHTML = person2.Title;
document.getElementById("code2").innerHTML = person2.Author;
document.getElementById("code3").innerHTML = person2.Type;
document.getElementById("code4").innerHTML = person2.Price;

document.getElementById("job1").innerHTML = person3.Title;
document.getElementById("job2").innerHTML = person3.Author;
document.getElementById("job3").innerHTML = person3.Type;
document.getElementById("job4").innerHTML = person3.Price;
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Objects</h2>

<button onclick="show(0)">Book 1</button>
<button onclick="show(1)">Book 2</button>
<button onclick="show(2)">Book 3</button>

<h3>Book 1</h3>
<p id="demo1"></p>         
<p id="demo2"></p>
<p id="demo3"></p>
<p id="demo4"></p>

<h3>Book 2</h3>
<p id="code1"></p>
<p id="code2"></p>
<p id="code3"></p>
<p id="code4"></p>

<h3>Book 3</h3>
<p id="job1"></p>
<p id="job2"></p>
<p id="job3"></p>
<p id="job4"></p>

</html>
```

So basically what I'm trying to achieve is that when I click on the buttons for book 1, book 2 or book 3 that the object will be displayed for example if I click on the button Book 1 the book title, Author, Type, Price and image will be displayed I'm stuck om how I'm supposed to do this and would be grateful for help on this.

Comment: You shouldn't have those HTML tags in your JavaScript code for starters.

Comment: Using `innerText` rather than `innerHTML` is safer (prevents injection), and it seems like there is no need for the latter there.

Comment: @UlysseBN Ok thanks very much for that information I'll remember that next time I'm doing an excersise like this

Comment: I just have one more question how would I be able to add an image into the code for example book 1 would have an image I select and the image to be displayed along with the information of the book when I click on the button book 1.

Comment: I've updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57323573/11074303) to include changing image. Please [mark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png) my answer as accepted if it helped you. @AkeemJokosenumi

Comment: @ArtuX thanks very much for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way this can be achieved:

```js
// Create book objects
var books = [
    {title: "A Song of Ice and Fire", author: "George RR Martin", type: "Paperback", price: 19.99, img: "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e48b39b77bf324de9aeefd6c5bfc10c6?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG"},
    {title: "The Woman in the Window", author: "A.J. Finn", type: "Paperback", price: 6.29, img: "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ee6e12042dc31b1ef27471482f9ff91f?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG"},
    {title: "The Silkworm", author: "Robert Galbraith", type: "Hardback", price: 14.99, img: "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/fa1648baa6108c85886312af93bb32c0?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG"},
];

// Display book details
function show(bookIndex) {
    var book = books[bookIndex];
    document.getElementById("bookTitle").innerText = book.title;
    document.getElementById("bookAuthor").innerText = book.author;
    document.getElementById("bookType").innerText = book.type;
    document.getElementById("bookPrice").innerText = book.price;
    document.getElementById("bookImg").src = book.img;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Objects</h2>

<button onclick="show(0)">Book 1</button>
<button onclick="show(1)">Book 2</button>
<button onclick="show(2)">Book 3</button>

<h3>Book details</h3>
<div>Title: <span id="bookTitle"></span></div>
<div>Author: <span id="bookAuthor"></span></div>
<div>Type: <span id="bookType"></span></div>
<div>Price: <span id="bookPrice"></span></div>
<div><img id="bookImg"/></div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A modified version of your code. I tried to add comments / notes to the code so you see what is in it, and why.

```js
// Create an arr ARRAY of OBJECTS
// then it can be filtered, grouped, etc.
// also give a unique ID to each book
// note that the keys of objects start with a
// lower case letter - convention, not necessity
var books = [{
  id: 0,
  title: "A Song of Ice and Fire",
  author: "George RR Martin",
  type: "Paperback",
  price: 19.99
}, {
  id: 1,
  title: "The Woman in the Window",
  author: "A.J. Finn",
  type: "Paperback",
  price: 6.29
}, {
  id: 2,
  title: "Title: The Silkworm",
  author: "Author: Robert Galbraith",
  type: "Type: Hardback",
  price: 14.99
}]

// "grab" all buttons
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('button')

// add a click event listener to all buttons
// with a callback function (a function that is called when the event occurs)
btns.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

  // the following line changes "Book 1", "Book 2", "Book 3"
  document.querySelectorAll('.book-number')[0].innerHTML = this.textContent

  // the following line triggers the displaying of book data
  displayBookData(this.getAttribute('data-bookid'), books)
}))

// create function that adds an HTML string to the container in the DOM
function displayBookData(bookId, bookArr) {
  document.querySelectorAll('.book-data')[0].innerHTML = createBookHtml(bookId, bookArr)
}

// function that actually assembles the HTML to be added to the DOM
function createBookHtml(bookId, bookArr) {

  //bookData will hold the actual data to be displayed
  const bookData = bookArr.filter(e => e.id == bookId)[0]

  // the following lines is the "template" of the HTML
  // to be displayed
  let html = `<p>Title: ${bookData.title}</p>
    <p>Author: ${bookData.author}</p>
    <p>Type: ${bookData.type}</p>
    <p>Price: ${bookData.price}</p>`

  // the HTML string is returned, so the caller function
  // will have something to append to the DOM
  return html
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <h2>JavaScript Objects</h2>

  <button data-bookid="0">Book 1</button>
  <button data-bookid="1">Book 2</button>
  <button data-bookid="2">Book 3</button>

  <h3 class="book-number"></h3>
  <div class="book-data"></div>
```

Comment: This is perfect I just have one more question and thats how would I be able to get an image to display along with the information when a button is clicked